# Laravel 5 - Eloquent relationship returning an empty collection

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm having trouble with a Laravel 5 relationship. I have 2 models `Crew` and `Event` with the corresponding tables `crews` and `events`.  Crews have many events, and events have one crew. I set up my models and migration as follows:

Schema:

```
//Crews
    Schema::connection('scheduling')->create('crews', function ($table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('name');
            $table->boolean('solo');
            $table->boolean('active');
            $table->text('phone');
        });

        //Events
        Schema::connection('scheduling')->create('events', function ($table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            // ...
            $table->integer('crew_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('crew_id')->references('id')->on('crews');
            $table->text('notes');
            // ...
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Models:

```
namespace App\Models\Scheduling;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Crew extends Model {

    public $connection = "scheduling";
    public $table = "crews";

    public function events() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Scheduling\Event', 'id', 'crew_id');
    }

    public static function active() {
        return Crew::where('active', 1)->get();
    }

}  

namespace App\Models\Scheduling;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Event extends Model {

    public $connection = "scheduling";
    public $table = "events";

    public function crew() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Scheduling\Crew', 'crew_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

If I run `Crew::find(102)->events;` I end up with an empty collection.
If I run `Events::where('crew_id', 102)->get();` I end up with the list of events I expected.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of **events** relation is invalid - you pass the arguments in wrong order.

Replace:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Scheduling\Event', 'id', 'crew_id');
```

with

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Scheduling\Event', 'crew_id', 'id');
```

or simply

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Scheduling\Event');
```

as you are using the default values for the column names, so no need to pass them to the relation definition.

Comment: Originally I had it like your suggested method, but that wasn't working for me so I tried what I currently have. I will try again in a few minutes here, just to be sure.

Comment: Well, I don't know what voodoo magic this is, but its working. I swear I had it setup just like this originally, but I must have had something else wrong. Either way, thank you!